# Merge Successive Push into Single for Code Review

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, pull-request

If we make some changes after pushing a branch for review and then notice minor mistakes, such as comment typo and make changes to those (or any change) and push. Is it possible to merge these two (or more as per case) iterations into single one for review purpose.

The issue I am trying to address is, when reviewers look at the code and notices two iteration, they maybe tempted to compare the last two, but it should really be both iterations combined and then compared with previous.

Except for preventive measure from Developer, does Git provide any options to merge successive push into one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily without `git rebase` or `git merge --squash`. In this example below I have squashed the last 2 commits.

If you want to write the new commit message from scratch, this suffices:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2 &&
git commit
```

If you want to start editing the new commit message with a concatenation of the existing commit messages (i.e. similar to what a pick/squash/squash/…/squash `git rebase -i` instruction list would start you with), then you need to extract those messages and pass them to `git commit`:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2 && 
git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"
```

Both of those methods squash the last two commits into a single new commit in the same way. The soft reset just re-points HEAD to the last commit that you do not want to squash. Neither the index nor the working tree are touched by the soft reset, leaving the index in the desired state for your new commit (i.e. it already has all the changes from the commits that you are about to “throw away”).

In your case, depending on if you want to just to put a review or to upload for review and commit you can choose.